# Standard Library function to convert an object providing operator<< to a std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, stdstring, ostream

I've just noticed that I am using the following code in my C++11 application (which works quiet fine):

```
template <typename T>
std::string output_streamable_to_string(T const& kObject) {
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << kObject;

  return os.str();
}
```

So my question is: Does a function exist in the Standard Library (`std`) that does provide this functionality?

I know that `std::to_string` exists, but that only works with Standard Library data types. I want to convert a `boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint` to a `std::string`. Since the `boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint` only provides an `operator<<` function, I do need to convert the `std::ostream` to a `std::string`.

Comment: I'm afraid it is already the Standard Library way to do it :-)

Comment: what you want is called serialization. Check out [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), [msgpack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c) or something like [picojson serializer](https://github.com/d-led/picojson_serializer)

Comment: @Dmitry Ledentsov: Using a serialization library/framework is **completely** overkill. I just want to convert a simple data type or object into a `std::string`. @ForEveR answered the question. I am aware of the first two of the libraries you mentioned.

Comment: I got the feeling that `to_string` might be a candidate for ADL use like `swap`, sadly boost doesn't really provide a `to_string` implementation for it yet.

Comment: @FlorianWolters of course, it depends on what you want. `T` is not defined in the scope of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such function in standard C++. But since you use boost - you can use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), or just use your own.

Comment: Really sad. :D But since I already use Boost.Asio in my current project, I will use `boost::lexical_cast` (already forgot that). I will keep the function in my original post for projects that do not need Boost.

Comment: boost's lexical_cast is a header only library anyway so it shouldn't matter if you just include that into a project that isn't 'using boost' as there won't be any external dependencies. and since it's templated the size increase should only be small